# Elasticsearch count aggregation number of buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

Given this elasticsearch query which mimics that sql request "select count(distinct(keyword))as nb from table"

```
{"aggs":{"nb":{"terms":{"field":"keyword","size":99999999}}}}
```

Is there any faster way of getting that total number of distinct keywords in my elastic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use the [cardinality](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) aggregation, which is exactly what you want (unique count of terms).